# ASP.NET MVC and HTML5 JavaScript Data Practices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, architecture

I am trying to figure out the best way to get data onto my webpages for use in JavaScript.

The majority of my experience is desktop land in .Net (WPF etc).

**Technology**:

I am currently using ASP.NET MVC3. I have a bunch of business layer models. These models can sometimes have interesting relationships. I need to get these models onto the client and do things in JavaScript with them and then send them back to the server for persistence and other business logic.

**Core Values**:

I would like to find a solution that minimizes coupling, minimizes code/functionality duplication, supports separation of concerns, and Easily maintainable (IE understandable, knowing where to change what etc.).

There are a few ways of handling this that I have thought of. Both seem to fall short.

**Option 1**:

Create JavaScript versions of my models that I will call JavaScript View Models (JSVMs). these JSVMs are created through Ajax calls. The JSVMs are mapped to from generated JavaScript objects based on the server-side models. That means there is a "Map" "class" somewhere that handles mapping to and from these two models (to lower coupling and maintain SoC).

Downside, Lots of code duplication. When you change either the JSVM or the server side model, you might need to change this mapping "class".

This seems to solve only some of my issues.

**Option 2**:

I found a library called "FluentJson.Net". It basically allows me to create knockoutjs JavaScript objects from razor inline. From there I can basically just code against this dynamically create object. There is no need to create the JSVMs.

Downside, There is very tight coupling to the server-side model. A change in the server-side model could cause needed changes on multiple pages!

There are probably some combinations of option 1 and option 2 that I could explore but I assume they will all have drawbacks.

**Questions**:

What I really would like to know is: what are the best practices for handling models across the server and client? Is there a solution that maintains my core values?

(Edit: Added the following example)

*EXAMPLE*:

**C# Models**:

```
public interface IChartDefinition{
    string Name{get; set};
    IEnumerable<IChartSeries> Series {get; set;}
}

public interface IChartSeries{
    Color Color{get; set;}
    Name {get; set;}
}
```

On the server this definition defines the basic chart. This chart definition is persisted to a database and can later be pulled up and used with real data to display a chart on the client.

I have a controller called "ChartDesignerController" and it's basic function is to let people manage their chart definitions.

So I have a view for called Create for creating a chart definition.  In my view I want a + button to add series. as series are added I want the UI to display options for the series such as color and name. The user can remove series etc.

All of this interaction is done with javascript on underlying javascript objects that hold this data until the end user pushes the submit button and send this data back to the server to be persisted.

These javascript objects will look almost identical to the C# models that get persisted.

Comment: Why do you need the model on the client other than for display?  In java script you are going to be working with the objects on the page and their values, what would be the advantage of duplicating your MVC structure in java script?

Comment: Maybe that is part of my problem. Alot of functionality needs to be representable on the client. That data needs to exist there somewhere and then be sent back to the server to make changes.

I dont think that I need to duplicate my entire set of models but some of them will need to be represented on the server for manipulation.

Comment: Option 3: Use JavaScript on the server and re-use your business models server/client. You  basically have a core Model and your server inherits from it and your client inherits from it. This maximises code re-use through inheritance

Comment: Are you suggesting Node.js? I'm working with asp.net MVC. I am not aware of a complete solutions for ASP.NET MVC with Node.js.

Comment: I don't see anything in your core values that mandates creating Javascript models.  What is making you think that you need to do that?  Why can't you use the asp.net MVC model with validation attirubtes to do the client side validation of your model?

Comment: I am going to add an example to my original question to help validate my meaning.